# How to create multipath device

Tags: linux, lvm

Running a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6.

Created new LUN, re-scanned the bus, created PV on one
of the 4 new devices created, then created VG-LV on te same.
The LUN is multi-pathed but I forgot to modify the
multipah.conf at blacklist_exceptions and multipaths 
section for the LUN.
So I ended up with:

```
PV Name               /dev/sdbq

/dev/disk/by-id

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 13 17:56 scsi-360002ac00000000055000b01000071a6 -> ../../sdbq
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 13 17:56 wwn-0x60002ac00000000055000b01000071a6 -> ../../sdbq

/dev/disk/by-path

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 13 17:52 pci-0000:04:00.1-fc-0x20210002ac0071a6-lun-16 -> ../../sdbn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 13 17:34 pci-0000:04:00.1-fc-0x21210002ac0071a6-lun-16 -> ../../sdbo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 13 17:34 pci-0000:07:00.1-fc-0x24220002ac0071a6-lun-16 -> ../../sdbp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 13 17:56 pci-0000:07:00.1-fc-0x25220002ac0071a6-lun-16 -> ../../sdbq
```

So, how can I create at this point the mpath device
that point at the LUN? And, how can I associate the multipathed device
to the PV?

Answer (score 0):

- create `multipath.conf` entry for `0x60002ac00000000055000b01000071a6`,
- entry following `alias` will give `/dev/mapper/name`
- re run multipath

  ```
  echo reconfigure | multipath -k
  ```
- this will keep `sdbq`
- run `pvscan` this should create link in `/dev/mapper`

Comment: Sorry, one more question. To associate the mpath device, instead of sdbq, to the PV, would a pvscan suffice? I want just to be sure that, in case of the path related to sdbq fails, the LV/VG will still be available.